# ng-grid Show Two Arrow Sorting Icon for Every Column Header

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

In ng-grid, there are two arrow icons for sorting, but it is not showing all arrows in every column header by default.
I know about setting `sortInfo`, but I don't want to sort when the ng-grid first initializes.

How can I show the two arrows for every column header without triggering the sorting?

*--Edited--*

For those requesting some code:
My `gridOptions` are standard.
I don't know what other code I should provide to you.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableHighlighting: true,
        sortInfo: { fields: [], columns: [], directions: [] },
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'name', displayName: 'Company'},
            {field: 'meta.orders', displayName: 'Orders'},
            {field: 'meta.expenses', displayName: 'Expenses', cellFilter: 'currency: \'IDR \''},
            {field: 'meta.commissions', displayName: 'Commisions', cellFilter: 'currency: \'IDR \''},
            {field: 'status', displayName: 'Status'},
            {field: '', cellTemplate: '<a ng-click="details(row)" class="btn btn-link" id="{{row.entity._id}}">Details</a>'}
        ]
    };
```

I want to achieve something like this (see the two arrows appear) when the ng-grid is first initialized, without triggering the sort:

[image: I want to achieve like this when the ng-grid first initialized. And without triggering the sort]

Comment: Can you provide some  piece of code ? ...

Comment: I don't think ng-grid has the ability to show both the arrows. It shows one and then if you click it, it changes in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Michelem Do you have any other idea how to achieve something like that? My point is i need to show the user if the column header are sortable

Comment: I cannot understand what you get now. BTW this should be removed: `sortInfo: { fields: [], columns: [], directions: [] },`

Comment: You want to show the icons to make it more visible/clearer that the columns are sortable, but without having to sort anything on init?

Comment: @JiaJian Yeah, something like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solved it.

I got the code below from the [ng-grid template docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Templating).

```
var customHeaderCellTemplate = '<div ng-click="col.sort()" ng-class="{ ngSorted: !noSortVisible }">'+
'<span class="ngHeaderText">{{col.displayName}}</span>'+
'<div class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="showSortUp(col)"></div>'+
'<div class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="showSortDown(col)"></div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div ng-show="col.allowResize" class="ngHeaderGrip" ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>';
```

I modified it with my custom scope in the `ng-show="showSortUp(col)"` and `ng-show="showSortDown(col)"`.

Then i put the `showSortUp(col)` and `showSortDown(col)` scope function in my controller.
The `col` params give us the info about the header column including sorting direction.
From the ng-grid source code, the showing arrows are controlled by sortDirection variable. In `col` params, we can get the sortDirection variable so we can use it to modify the original behaviour.

```
$scope.showSortUp = function(col) {
    if(col.sortDirection == 'asc') {
        return true;
    } else if(col.sortDirection == 'desc') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


$scope.showSortDown = function(col) {
    if(col.sortDirection == 'desc') {
        return true;
    } else if(col.sortDirection == 'asc') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to modify the `.ngSortButtonUp` and `.ngSortButtonDown` css because the original styles are broken when you show both arrows together.